# How to set validations for textbox null value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

this is my code which creates text and number column-

```
     using Microsoft.SharePoint;
     using System;
    using System.IO;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
      using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
     using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks; 
   using System.Windows.Forms;

      namespace Project_Site_Updation_Utility
   {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void WriteLog()
    {
        StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
        File.WriteLine("Data Time:" + DateTime.Now);
        File.WriteLine("Column Name:" + txtColumnName.Text);
        File.Close();
    }


    private void Createcalsite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(txtPWAUrl.Text))
         {
            oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                foreach (SPWeb projsite in oSPWeb.Webs)
                {

                    if (projsite.WebTemplate.ToString().ToLower() == "projectsite")
                    {
                        if (projsite.Title == "proj2")
                        {

                            SPList lst = projsite.Lists[txtListName.Text];

                            var kk = txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "_x0020_");
                                if
                                    (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Singleline")
                                {


                                    if (!lst.Fields.ContainsField(txtColumnName.Text))
                                    {

                                        SPFieldText fldName = (SPFieldText)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                        SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);

                                        fldName.MaxLength = 200;
                                        fldName.DefaultValue = txtMultilineDefault.Text;
                                        lst.Fields.Add(fldName);

                                    }


                                }
                                if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Number")
                                {
                                    if (!lst.Fields.ContainsField(txtColumnName.Text))
                                    {

                                        SPFieldNumber fldEmpID = (SPFieldNumber)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                        SPFieldType.Number.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                        lst.ValidationMessage = "Enter COlumn NAme";
                                        fldEmpID.DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.NoDecimal;
                                        fldEmpID.DefaultValue = txtMultilineDefault.Text;
                                        lst.Fields.Add(fldEmpID);
                                         }

                                    }
                    }

                        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }

                    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Update Successfully");
            WriteLog();
        }
```

`txtPWAUrl.Text` in this text box i am passing URL

`txtColumnName.Text` in this textbox I am passing column name which want to create

`txtListName.Text` in this textbox I am passing  list name

cmbDataType-this is my combo box

how to set validation in my code that is any of my text box remains empty it shows message.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check whether the `textbox` is null or not,

```
if(txtColumnName.Text != null)
```

OR

```
if(txtColumnName.Text != "")
```

OR

```
if(txtColumnName.Text != string.Empty)
```

Similar condition you can use for other `textboxes`.

and put one label in red color under textbox make visible showing message if null `"that please enter appropriate values"`.

Or give server side alert box for the empty textbox as,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"showalert","alert('Please enter appropriate values');",true);
```